# SpringBoot BackboneJs requirejs springsecirity webapp

Tags: backbone.js, spring-security, requirejs, spring-boot

I am assigned a task to have a poc for using spring security with backbonejs
.The design is that the user should be served a login page and after login our index page has to be rendered and if login is unsuccessful then login template has to be rerendered.Can anyone help me in getting started with this.After a lot of research I am not able to figure out a proper design.

Answer (score 0):

Using backbone often implies a Single Page Application .  Security in a Single Page App is different than server (backend) rendered application.  Below is a good blog article with some code snippets to get you started.  If the server is not rendering the page then all spring security can do is protect the REST endpoints that BackboneJS is calling.

http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/01/03/spring-security-csrf-protection-in-a-backbone-single-page-app/